# Angular2 listen for global event

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I've a third party script, which is **not** a npm module. So what I did, is I added it as a normal script to my `index.html`, because there is just no way around that.

```
<script src="https://myExternalScript.js"></script>
```

Once this `myExternalScript.js` loaded, it will download another *js* file, which then calls a function called `onDiagramReady()`. I've to implement `onDiagramLoaded()`. So to be able to catch this event, I've added my `onDiagramLoaded()` to my `index.html`. Which look like this:

```
function onDiagramReady() {
  window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('onDiagramReady', {detail: this.Diagram}));
}
```

In my component I've a `@HostListener` to be able to get the context into it. This looks like this:

```
  @HostListener('window:onDiagramReady', ['$event'])
  onReactomeDiagramReadyListener(event) {
    //magic in my component  
  }
```

So this was working perfectly fine in Angular 2.0, but now I get an error in my console: [image]

It is still working, but I don't know what to do about this error. Is there maybe a better way to make a function available to the global scope?